# Subviews of custom UIView are equal to nil even after view is loaded

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm trying to render a custom view. The problem is that even after the view is loaded, its subviews are still equals to nil.. So not showing and impossible to configure. The custom view is setup through interface builder and all the outlets are linked to the properties you can see below.

Here is the custom UIView code :

```
import UIKit

class BadgeView : UIView
{
    @IBOutlet weak var progressCircleView: CircleProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressionValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Tell me if you need more informations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How do you initialise `BadgeView`. If you are using storyboard or xib, the view should be initialised like this:

```
let nib = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("BadgeView", owner: self, options: nil)
let badgeView = nib[0] as! BadgeView
```

Comment: I'm instanciating it in a xib fil so it should be ok about this, should not it ? I mean, it is itself a subview or another custom view.

Comment: It will not be automatically initialised during the initialisation of `YourCustomView`. So you have to add it manually, I mean `yourCustomView.addSubView(badgeView)`.

Comment: But the badge view is already in the view.. I changes background to be sure and the view is hère. But all subview are equal to nil.

Comment: Yes the badge view is in the view. But it is not initialised from the `xib`, it is actually initialised from `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`, thats why all its subviews are nil.

Comment: hey bro. I want to create BadgeView from storyboard. But always get nil (childrent view of BadgeView). How can i solve it? Thanks you